# Calculating chance of event over time from sample data

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I am doing the following experiment:

I have slots which I monitor, the slot can either be occupied / free. The study is per slot, so we are discussing one slot here.

Every now and then I receive the following indications for example: `s(2)=free`, which means that once a spot was free (after it was occupied) it remained free for at least 2 minutes. I collect all these data (the signals `s(2)`, etc.) into tables. Here is another example: `s(4)=occupy`, which means that this slot was free at some point and then 4 minutes after it was occupied.

I want to answer the question: **what is the chance that a spot will remain free for X minutes?**

In an attempt to answer this, I divided it into intervals (1-2 minutes, 2-3 minutes, ... , up to 10 minutes, which is the max). I then placed each sample into an interval with its value (free / occupy). For example, for the 3-4 minute interval, I have 120 free, and 60 occupy. So for this interval i(3)=120/120+60=0.66 = 66% that it is free in this interval. I know what i(1)=.. i(2)=.. etc., are as well.

**How do I take into account the other interval data that I have?** Clearly the chances that the spot remains free in the next 3 minutes is not 66%, but is also based on other interval results.

Answer (score 1):

Rephrase the question as "How long before the slot closes?" Then you can look at it as 10 minutes before it closes; 9 minutes before it closes ... 1 minute before it closes. That way you're doing the groups as having to stay open the entire time, instead of (for example) having to include groups > 4 minutes as still being open at 4 minutes.

Does that help at all?

Comment: i dont see how.